# How to automatically change Eclipse build path when I check out Git branches

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I'm using Eclipse Helios and EGit 0.11.3.

I have a project where different branches use different versions of some of the libraries on my Java build path. For example, `branch_old` uses `foo_lib_v1.0.jar` while `branch_new` uses `foo_lib_v2.0.jar`.

If I'm working on `branch_new` and I need to checkout `branch_old` to test something, it's a bit of a hassle: I must manually reconfigure the build path in Eclipse before the project can build successfully.

Is there a way to store Eclipse's Java build path configuration for my project in git, so that when I check out a branch the build path is automatically modified? If not, is there another way to achieve the same result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several choices here:

- **store project files** (`.classpath` and `.project`) **in Git as part of your branch**. This way you would have to store all your dependencies in Git too, which is a hassle if you have a lot of them.
- **use Maven (m2eclipse plugin) and store project definition** (`pom.xml`) file as part of your version control. Maven will greatly simplify your project dependency configuration

More information on m2eclipse plugin can be found at http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/

Comment: Adding .classpath to git does the trick.  I'll look into m2eclipse.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Should work: Put the `.buildpath` under version control. So its checkouted every time you switch the branches.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Eclipse stores his build classpath in a file like .classpath(?) You can just add the file to git and have an own config for each branch.

Answer (score 1):

Define several user libraries in your workspace, such as FooLib1, FooLib2, FooLib2. Then in the project's build path at a given branch reference the appropriate version of the library. Make sure you include project metadata files such as .classpath in your git repository and you should be set.